# Python Can I use gspread delete row in google sheet which create by google form?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I create google form and save data when user fill out google form to google sheet.  After that I use gspread read data and create csv file. I want to remove all data in google sheet after python create csv file already. I user this code

```
worksheet = sheet.get_worksheet(0)
worksheet.delete_row(1)
```

It show this error.

```
APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].deleteDimension: Cannot delete row with form questions. Consider hiding the row instead.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

Can I use gspread delete row  in google sheet which create by google form ?

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is that you are trying to delete the top row - the one that contains the headers.

This is not possible, but you can delete all other rows.

> Note: Your first form response will be in the second row - since the
>   first one contains the headers.